# How do you add different opacities to nested items?

Tags: html, css

I have two nested items in HTML and I want to give the wrraping one opacity 0.8 and the one inside it opacity 1.
I think I understand why it does not work, but, how can I mimick that effect?
Here is a simplified HTML that shows the problem, I want the green square to be solid.

```
<div style='background-color:red;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            opacity:0.8'>

    <div style='width:150px; height:150px; background-color:green; opacity:1'>
      Some content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use the `rgba` CSS property instead of the opacity property you can achieve this:

```
<div style='background-color:rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.8) ;width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0'>
<div style='position: relative; width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);'>aaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaa<br></div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ScHgC/

Comment: `rgba` is really the way to effect this since you don't have to mess around with wrapper div's, of course, IE is the issue.

Comment: In that case I would use transparent pngs in conjuntion with DD_belated png fix (in a conditional stylesheet for IE) or perhaps you can use CSS3Pie, although it has limited support for rgba http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#rgba

Comment: Thank you for posting about CSS3 Pie.  This is new to me, will likely to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

you could always embrace progressive enhancement and use [rgba](http://24ways.org/2009/working-with-rgba-colour) on your background-colors

```
// this will only affect the div it's applied to and not it's contents
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8)
```

Comment: ps - since this doesn't work in some browsers, it's considered progressive enhancement - you can use [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to help out with that side of things though

Comment: Regarding my answer, noted. I tested it out, mine didn't work. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

**Using CSS2**

I fiddled a demo for you that illustrates a key concept:

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/pN69F/

You can start by adding a `wrapper` div to position your two enclosed div's, `outer` and `inner`.  The `outer` comes before the `inner`, which means that the `inner` will sit over the `outer` (unless you adjust the z-index values).

You can set the opacity to the `outer` div and that will allow any background text or image to be partly visible.  Set the opacity of the `inner` div to 1.0 to get fully saturated coloring.

I think most browsers support opacity, but check out http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html for vendor-specific CSS properties to handle IE quirks.