# HTML/CSS 'rgba' CSS property not workingThe opacity of the inner div is not coming fully opaque

Tags: html, css

I have made eight small div boxes, four in each row, which are contained in a bigger 'wrapper' div box. I want the outer div to be transparent and the inner ones to be completely opaque white. I saw the solution on this link
[How do you add different opacities to nested items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237843/how-do-you-add-different-opacities-to-nested-items)
 and tried the 'rgba' property. The outer div became completely transparent but the problem is that the inner divs are semi-transparent, not opaque. I have realized that this happens because of the transparency of the outer div. It's like the outer div is covering the inner divs with a veil of its own transparency and hence preventing the inner divs to be fully opaque. But how do I fix that? This is my code-
HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
opacity:0.7;
width:1043px; 
height:800px; 
}
#small {
margin: 30px; 
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border: 0px;
float:left; 
position:relative; 
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); 
}
```

Somebody please help?

Comment: show us a jsfiddle of your code

Comment: Remove the `opacity` from the parent div.

Comment: I removed the opacity from the parent div. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: id is meant to be unique. more is explained in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first, RGBA stands for Red, Green , Blue and Alpha.

Alpha is just like `opacity` and you were giving the `opacity` to the parent. If you place it in the alpha place it will work.

Second, `opacity` from parents always get inherited by their children.

Here is the solution:

```css
#wrapper {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
width:1043px; 
height:800px; 
}
#small {
margin: 30px; 
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border: 0px;
float:left; 
position:relative; 
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="small"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the wrapper's `opacity` to .7 makes everything inside the wrapper opaque.

http://jsfiddle.net/sdz546pg/

```
#wrapper {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
width:1043px; 
height:800px; 
}
#wrapper>div {
margin: 30px; 
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border: 0px;
float:left; 
position:relative; 
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); 
}
```

Removing opacity and changing the alpha value inside the `background-color` of the main `wrapper` makes only the wrapper semitransparent.The content is so shown normally.

I personally prefer `hsla()` over `rgba()` when playing with opacity and colors in general.Sometimes you just want everything lighter or maybe less saturated. doing that with rgba is a mess.

```
hsla(HUE,SATURATION,LIGHTNESS,ALPHA)
hsla(0-360,0%-100%,0%-100%,0-1) /*hsla(200,99%,51%,.7548)*/

hsla(0,100%,50%,1); /*red*/
hsla(0,0%,50%,1); /*grey*/
hsla(0,0%,50%,.5); /*50% opaque grey*/
hsla(0,0%,100%,1); /*white*/
hsla(0,0%,0%,1); /*black*/
```

If you have any questions just ask.

> Said that, you have another **ERROR** inside your code. `id` is meant
>   to be **unique**, replace id with `class="small"`. or use
>   `#wrapper>div` to give your nested elements the desiderated style.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```